# RandomForest returns wrong number of trees

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I am trying to predict churn of customer using Random Forest. I am following this [article](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/predicting-customer-churn-with-sklearn.html).

However I am stuck with part 8 (ln[8] and Out[8]) - I want to use only 10 estimators (to have only 10 trees) so predictors are all multiples of 0.1.

Below, I simplified my code to just clean the data, predict the model and see the estimators, **but they are not multiples of 0.1**. Why?

```
churn_df = pd.read_csv('C:/path')
col_names = churn_df.columns.tolist()

#Separate target data
churn_res = churn_df['CLI_ACT']
y = np.where(churn_res == True,1,0)

#Drop useless columns now
to_drop = ['   ', 'CLI_ID_S', 'LST_MONTH_PAY', 'CLI_ACT']
churn_clean = churn_df.drop(to_drop,axis=1)

#Convert training data to numpy matrix as floats
X = churn_clean.as_matrix().astype(np.float)

#Standardize the data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)

prob = RF(n_estimators=10).fit(X_train,y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
print np.unique(prob)
```

The output array has 38 elements(=Trees) with various probabilities (0, 0.3333, 0.937...) instead of array of 10 elements(=Trees) from 0.0 to 1.0 by 0.1.

Answer (score 2):

Per the relevant `sklearn` [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba), `predict_proba()` returns an array with dimensions equal to the number of samples and the number of classes. (NB that the number of classes is not the number of trees.) More, the returned probabilities are the average of the trees:

> The predicted class probabilities of an input sample is computed as the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest.

Per the `np.unique()` [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), this array will be flattened if it's more than single-dimensional. Meaning, without your data at hand, there's really no way to know why you're winding up with 38 elements. But in any case, you wouldn't expect predicted probability dimension to align with the number of classifiers.

Since `predict_proba()` averages the predictions of the set of $k$ classifiers, it will only give a multiple $\frac{1}{k}$ when all of these classifiers give $0$ or $1$ probabilities for a given datum. This will only occur when:

1. The data are separable by a set of boolean conjunctions. Meaning, rules can be constructed such that every node of the tree is solely of a single class.
2. The trees are trained to adequate depth to fully fit—overfit, some might say—the data.

If your code is working to separate toy sets, say `load_digits()` in `sklearn`, it would seem your data can't be fully separated by decision trees.

`RandomForestClassifier` *does* make the underlying classifiers available, however, as detailed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17065429/1876158). To get a clearer picture, you could access this attribute to find the predictions of the underlying trees.

Comment: Hi, I have attached the data sample. If you look at it, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @SeanEaster is right, number of columns is a number of classes that you have in your target column.

Comment: @itdxer I see it now, but that's why I have the argument `n_estimators=10`. To control the number of classes.

Comment: @HonzaB I'm not sure what you mean by "control the number of classes." The number of classes is a characteristic of the learning problem, e.g. when classifying the ten numeral digits, the number of classes is necessarily 10. 'n_estimators' refers to the number of classifiers used in the ensemble, which is wholly separate from the number of classes. Are you trying to create 'n' one-vs-all classifiers, perhaps?

Comment: @SeanEaster Sorry, I am not really fluent in this terminology. What I am trying to do is get probability in 10 classes, from 0.0 to 1.0 by 0.1. I thought I can do this with `n_estimators=10` as in the website I have mentioned. It works for them, but not for me.

Comment: @HonzaB Ah, now I see what you mean. You were expecting the probabilities to be the average of predictions of the underlying trees, a vote of sorts, in which case all probabilities would be multiples of 0.1. Is that correct? If so, I can think of a few reasons this might not occur. Per the current docs, each tree predicts the mean of the values at the terminal node; this will only be 0 or 1 if the tree is fully fit to the data. So it may be that your trees can't fully fit, or that there's been a change in sklearn since that article was published. (There's been a new stable release since then.)

Comment: @HonzaB Try running your code on a toy dataset, like the `sklearn` digits data. I ran an adapted version of your code and got 0.1 multiples, so it's likely a matter of how the underlying trees fit your data. (That would explain the other values, the forest is averaging values other than 0 and 1.)

Comment: @SeanEaster Yes, that's what I mean. I did tests on various sets and also reproduce the code in the article. Always works, but not with my data. Thank you for help, I will have a better look at my model. At least now I am sure I dont have logical error.